# Bridging Header Deleted in Parse Project

Tags: objective-c, swift, parse-platform, ios8, bridging-header

I accidentally deleted my bridging header file for a Parse project in swift. And it wasn't just a reference removal. I since created a new bridging header but when I go to run the application, the error message says "bridging header at < insert location here> doesn't exist".

Comment: Create a new bridging header file and clean and compile or  just put it back to your project directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clear all from this list and later just drag and drop your new Bridging-Header file to here

[image]